# How to implement custom Perl::PrereqScanner::NotQuiteLite parser

Tags: perl, dbix-class

Tried to write a custom parser to find modules loaded via [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class) `load_components` as follows:

```
# lib/DBIC.pm
package DBIC;

use 5.026;
use Perl::PrereqScanner::NotQuiteLite::Util;

sub register {
    return { use => { 'DBIx::Class::Core' => 'parse_dbic' } };
}

sub parse_dbic {
    die 'We never reach this point';
}

1;
```

Tested it with:

```
# t/dbic.t
use 5.026;
use Test2::V0 -target => 'DBIC';
use Perl::PrereqScanner::NotQuiteLite;

my $scanner = Perl::PrereqScanner::NotQuiteLite->new( parsers => [':bundled', '+DBIC'] );
my $string  = <<'EOF';
package My::Schema;
use base 'DBIx::Class::Core';
__PACKAGE__->load_components('UUIDColumns');
EOF

subtest 'DBIC custom parser' => sub {
    is( $scanner->scan_string($string)->requires->as_string_hash,
        {   'base'                     => 0,
            'DBIx::Class::Core'        => 0,
            'DBIx::Class::UUIDColumns' => 0,
        },
        'should find dependencies declared via "load_components"',
    );
};

done_testing;
```

Have looked through other parsers including:

- [Aliased](https://metacpan.org/release/Perl-PrereqScanner-NotQuiteLite/source/lib/Perl/PrereqScanner/NotQuiteLite/Parser/Aliased.pm)
- [Module::Runtime](https://metacpan.org/release/Perl-PrereqScanner-NotQuiteLite/source/lib/Perl/PrereqScanner/NotQuiteLite/Parser/ModuleRuntime.pm)
- [Moose](https://metacpan.org/release/Perl-PrereqScanner-NotQuiteLite/source/lib/Perl/PrereqScanner/NotQuiteLite/Parser/Moose.pm)

From the implementations it seems the above implementation should cause `parse_dbic` to get called.

Is there something missing that should trigger the function to get called?